# Remove specific folder name from url using htaccess in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3, hmvc

I want to remove particular module name from the url in codeigniter application.

My URLs:

```
http://app.example.loc/admin/index/
http://app.example.loc/members/index/
http://example.loc/funnel/index/
```

So I just want to remove members and funnel from URL which is basically module name.

My htaccess code:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|members|funnel|(.*)\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|jquery|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

But it gives me an error.

My route.php code:

```
switch ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'app.example.loc':
        // Members routing
        $route['default_controller'] = "members/index";
        $route['members/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "members/$1/$2/$3";

        // Admin routing
        $route['admin/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "admin/$1/$2/$3";
        break;
    default:
        // Funnel routing
        $route['default_controller'] = "funnel/index";
        $route['funnel/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "funnel/$1/$2/$3";
        break;
}
```

So basically I'm trying to redirect all traffic of admin module on /admin URL and for members want to load url without /members/ . (Same case for funnel)